# Why does `importlib.resources` require `__init__.py`?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

When writing a python package that includes resources such as sample data files, why is it necessary to have an `__init__.py` in the (sub)package? (Or is this only a pre-3.7 quirk?)

The current recommended way of accessing resources is using `importlib.resources` (or in pre-3.7 versions `importlib_resources`; rather than `pkg_resources` which had performance problems or `__file__` manipulations which are fragile depending on distribution methods). However, this only detects resources in a package directory if there is an `__init__.py` file (which can be empty).

Python had long been moving away from requiring `__init__.py` files (e.g. Guido [addressed](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-April/064400.html) controversy/pitchforks back at version 2.5), and now (since [PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)) omitting any empty `__init__.py` results in an *implicit namespace package* (and also permits splitting a single package among separate directories).  But for some reason `importlib_resources` at least does not support this?

Comment: See [Allow resources to be in subdirectories](https://gitlab.com/python-devs/importlib_resources/issues/58) for related discussion.